# Why is this Javascript not hiding the HTML items?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a script that's supposed to hide a certain item of an HTML list but it's not working. I reviewed the code several times yet I can't find what's wrong with it.

This is the function I've been using:

```
  hidecba() {
     var cba = document.getElementById('cba');
     cba.style.display = 'none';
 }
 hidestafe() {
     var stafe = document.getElementById('stafe');
     stafe.style.display = 'none';
 }
 hidebsas() {
     var bsas = document.getElementById('bsas');
     bsas.style.display = 'none';
 }
```

And this is the HTML code that it's supposed to hide:

```
<ul id="lista1">
    <li id="cba" value="cba" onclick="hidecba()">Córdoba</li>
    <li id="stafe" value="stafe" onclick="hidestafe()">Santa Fe</li>
    <li id="bsas" value="bsas" onclick="hidebsas()">Buenos Aires</li>
</ul>
```

Also, here's a JSFiddle with the HTML and Javascript altogether:

https://jsfiddle.net/fxwfran/6vp1ugcb/2/

Comment: Any code and markup related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: Fixed it already, thanks for the info, I'm new to JSFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the web console, you'll see an error there. (Top tip: Use the tools the browser gives you.)

You're missing the word `function`:

```
    function hidecba(){
//  ^^^^^^^^
        var cba = document.getElementById('cba');
        cba.style.display='none';
    }
```

There are also all kinds of other issues with that fiddle, such as:

```
<li id="tucu" value="tucu" onclick="function(#tucu)">Tucumán</li>
```

1. `li` elements have no `value` attribute
2. The JavaScript in the `onclick` attribute is invalid (`function` is not a function name)
3. If `function` were a function name, you'd need quotes around `#tucu`.
4. But ideally, you'd just use `this`, since it already refers to the element

Here's a simple example of hiding a list item when you click it using an `onxyz` handler:

```js
function hideElement(element) {
  element.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="hideElement(this)">Click to hide (1)</li>
  <li onclick="hideElement(this)">Click to hide (2)</li>
  <li onclick="hideElement(this)">Click to hide (3)</li>
  <li onclick="hideElement(this)">Click to hide (4)</li>
</ul>
```

...but I wouldn't use `onxyz` attributes for this. I suggest reading up on `addEventListener` (and its Microsoft cousin `attachEvent`).

Comment: I've fixed the first three issues but now the console says `hidecba` is not defined. What do you mean with using `this`?

Comment: @Fraaaan: If you're doing this on jsFiddle, it has a really stupid^H^H^H^H^H^H surprising default in that it wraps all your code in a `window.onload = function() { /* your code here */ };` that it doesn't show you. That means your functions aren't globals, which means you can't use them from `onxyz` attributes (one of many reasons not to use `onxyz` attributes). In jsFiddle, click the word JavaScript and choose "No wrap - body" to remove that wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! It finally worked, this has solved the issue!

Comment: @Fraaaan: I added an example of what I meant about `this` above. Glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Bad**

```
*function* hidecba(){
var cba = document.getElementById('cba');
cba.style.display='none';
}
```

**Good**

```
<ul id="myul">
    <li>click me1</li>
    <li>click me2</li>
    <li>click me3</li>
    <li>click me4</li>
</ul>
var myul=document.getElementById("myul");
    function hideEle(ele){
        ele.style.display='none';
    }
    myul.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        hideEle(e.target)
    });
```